# Help understanding proof verification: Prove if n is a perfect square, n+2 is not a perfect square

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

Prove if n is a perfect square, n+2 is not a perfect square

> Assume n is a perfect square and n+2 is a perfect square (proof by
>   contradiction)
>
> There exists positive integers a and b such that $n = a^2$ and $n + 2= b^2$
>
> Then $a^2 + 2 = b^2$
>
> Then $2 = b^2-a^2$
>
> Then $2 = (b-a)(b+a)$
>
> Then $b+a = 2$ and $b-a=1$          ***where does this come from?***
>
> Then $a = 1/2$ and $b=3/2$
>
> This is a contradiction because a and b should be positive integers.
>   Therefore if n is a perfect square, n+2 is not a perfect square.

Where does the $b+a = 2$ and $b-a=1$ come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to factor $2$ and the only factorization into two terms is $2 \cdot 1$.  Since $a,b$ are positive, $b+a \gt b-a$ so we take $b+a=2, b-a=1$

Answer (score 0):

Alternative direct proof: if $n=k^2$ for $k \ge 1$ then $(k+1)^2 = k^2 + 2k + 1\gt k^2 + 2 = n+2 \gt k^2\,$ so $n+2$ lies strictly between squares of consecutive numbers, thus cannot be a perfect square.