# Prove: If n is a perfect square, then n+3 is not a perfect square

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

Use either direct proof, proof by contrapositive, or proof by contradiction.

Using proof by contradiction method

> Assume n is a perfect square and n+3 is a perfect square (proof by
> contradiction)
>
> There exists integers x and y such that $n = x^2$ and $n+3 = y^2$
>
> Then $x^2 + 3 = y^2$
>
> Then $3 = y^2 - x^2$
>
> Then $3 = (y-x)(y+x)$
>
> Then $y+x = 3$ and $y-x=1$
>
> Then $x = 1, y = 2$
>
> Since $x = 1$, that implies $n = 1$
>
> ***this is how far I got***

Anyone know what I should do now?

Comment: Well, if you take $n=1$ you can see that the statement is false.

Comment: You have just disproved the statement. $n=1$ is a perfect square. So is $n+3=4$.

Comment: I am not entirely certain that you are proving anything true, without any more quantifiers at least. You tried in your proof and you got that $n$ can be equal to 1, and certainly 1 is a perfect square and 1+3 = 4 is also a perfect square, so I don't know if you're proving anything true

Comment: If you have the condition that $n>1$ then you reach a contradiction at the end.

Comment: This is a virtual duplicate of yesterday's [Help understanding proof verification: Prove if n is a perfect square, n+2 is not a perfect square](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2330514/help-understanding-proof-verification-prove-if-n-is-a-perfect-square-n2-is-no).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, as mentioned by others, $1$ is a perfect square and $1+3$ is a perfect square. So you need to prove "If $N > 1$ is a perfect square, then $n+3$ is not a perfect square.

Let $n = m^2$ where $m$ and $n$ are positive integers and $n > 1$. Then we must have $m > 1$. Since $m$ is an integer, we can say that $m \ge 2$. Hence $2m+1 \ge 5$. So

$$(m+1)^2 = m^2 + (2m+1) \ge n + 5 > n+3$$

Since $n < n+3 < n+5$, then $m^2 < n+3 < (m+1)^2$

Answer (score 1):

$$
3=y^2-x^2 \ge (x+1)^2-x^2= 2x+1
$$
which is false if $x>1$.

Answer (score 0):

You have proved that if $n$ and $n+3$ are perfect squares, $n=1=1^2, n+3=4=2^2$  The statement you were trying to prove is false.  Maybe you were also given $n \gt 1$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $n=4$ (a perfect square).  Note that $n+3 = 7$ is not a perfect square.

Is there anything more to this problem than that?

(Of course if $n=1$ (a perfect square) then $n+3 = 4$ happens to be a perfect square.)